# Need first six observations to calculate correctly in a python wma rolling average

Tags: python, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate weighted moving average for all the time series values in a pandas data frame for a window size of 7. For some reason it returns NaN for the first 6 observations, starting at the 7th observation, it is returning the correct value. While the 7th value is correct, there is definitely something wrong with my approach. Any suggestions or ideas on how to correct? Thank you in advance!

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

def calc_wma(df, wd_size, weights=1):
    """
    Takes in a series and calculates the WMA with a window size of wd_size
    """
    wma = None
    if isinstance(weights, int):
        weights = np.full(wd_size, weights)

    assert len(weights) == wd_size, "Q4: The size of the weights must be the same as the window size. "

    weights = np.arange(1, wd_size + 1)
    wma=df.rolling(7).apply(lambda cases: np.dot(cases, weights)/weights.sum(), raw=True)
    return wma


calc_wma(df,7)



Out: 
2020-01-23  NaN
2020-01-24  NaN
2020-01-25  NaN
2020-01-26  NaN
2020-01-27  NaN
2020-01-28  NaN
2020-01-29  1034.107143
2020-01-30  1350.714286
2020-01-31  1503.250000
2020-02-01  1710.071429
2020-02-02  2518.607143
2020-02-03  2769.714286
2020-02-04  3166.750000
2020-02-05  3448.714286
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot calculate a 7 day moving average for the first 6 days of your sample, that is why there are missing values on the first 6 days of the output.

Comment: Thank you, Pablo. That actually makes sense what you said. I need averages for those first six days too. So I suppose I will have to reconstruct my function to figure out how to loop through applying only the right rolling window for each of those. If anyone has any ideas on how to do that, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks